# Analytically continuing the limit of this series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

### Main Question

I believe the following formula gives the right answer:

$$   \lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{n h \to k} \left( \sum_{r=1}^n c_r f(hr) h\right) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx \times \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{a_r} r   $$

Where $$ c_r =  \sum_{d\mid r} a_d $$

And $f(x)$ is a continuous  function and its integral converges. How do I prove it rigorously and as the R.H.S looks familiar to a Dirichlet series can I analytically continue the L.H.S?

### My Heuristic Reasoning

We define the following basis:
$$ A_n= ( \underbrace{00000\ldots}_{n-1\text{ times}} 1 )^T $$

Hence,

$$ A_1  =(111111 \ldots )^T $$
$$ A_2 = (010101 \ldots)^T $$
$$ A_3 = (001001 \ldots)^T $$
To prove it is a complete basis we have to prove:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i A_i = C $$

where $ a_ i$ are coeffiencts and  $ C $ is an arbitrary vector.

We map this to a polynomial and write it explicitly as:

$$ a_1(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots) $$
$$ + $$
$$ a_2(x^2 + x^4 +  x^6+ \cdots ) $$
$$ + $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ = c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3 + \cdots$$

If we define:
$$ k(x)= a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots $$

We get:
$$ k(x) + k(x^2) + \cdots = c(x) $$

We note by comparing coefficients of $x^n$:

$$ c_n = \sum_{d\mid n} a_d $$

### Application to Integration

Consider an integral such that $$ \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = C,$$where, $f(x)$ is a smooth and continuous function and absolutely converges.

Now we raise both sides to the power s:

$$\left(\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx\right)^s = C^s $$

We substitute $x$ with $rx$ to get:

$$\left(\int_0^\infty f(rx) \, dx\right)^s = (C/r)^s $$

Multiplying both sides by an arbitrary coefficient:

$$ (a_r)\left(\int_0^\infty f(rx) \, dx\right)^s = (a_r)( C/r)^s $$

Taking their sum:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty a_r \left(\int_0^\infty f(rx) \, dx\right)^s = C^s \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{a_r}{r^s}   $$

We write the integral as a limit of a sum:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty  \lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{n h \to k}\ a_r \left( \sum_{x=1}^n f(hrx) h\right)^s = C^s \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{a_r}{r^s}   $$

### $s=1$ Case

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty  \lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{n h \to k}\ a_r \left( \sum_{x=1}^n f(hrx) h\right) = C \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{a_r} r   $$

For this case we write the sum explictly:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} a_1 h(f(h) + f(2h) + f(3h) +f(4h) + f(5h) + f(6h) + \cdots)$$
$$+$$
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} a_2 h(0.f(h) + f(2h) + 0.f(3h) +f(4h) + 0.f(5h) + f(6h) + \cdots)$$
$$+$$
$$ \vdots $$

We notice a striking similarity between the above and:

$$a_1( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\cdots)$$
$$+$$
$$a_2( 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1\ldots)$$
$$+$$
$$ \vdots $$

Hence,

$$   \lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{n h \to c} \left( \sum_{r=1}^n c_r f(hr) h\right) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx \times \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{a_r} r   $$

Where $$ c_r =  \sum_{d\mid r} a_d $$

Comment: for given $n$ inner limit by $h$ equals 0

Comment: With $c_r=1$, for each $n$ we have $\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \sum_{r=1}^n f(hr) h\right) = 0$

Comment: Upper limit in integral is $nh$, not $n$

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post with the $nh$ limit ...

Comment: Reason for the downvote? (So next time I don't do the same mistake?)

Comment: We should probably require more than just continuity of $f$. Maybe, that integral of $\int dx \sup_{x>t} |f(t)|<\infty$ or something like  that, which allows to bound partial Riemann sums.